# Como selecionar categorias e contar número de produtos de cada categoria?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando selecionar as categorias do banco de dados e contar na mesma query o número de produtos cadastrados naquela categoria. Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que não consigo que retorne a categoria quando não existe nenhum produto cadastrado, por exemplo:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.nome,t1.imagem,COUNT(*) AS Quantidade_produtos 
FROM categorias_produtos AS t1 
INNER JOIN produtos AS t2 ON t2.ref=t1.id 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Tenho as categorias:

```
categoria1
categoria2
categoria3
```

Produtos:

```
produto1 -> categoria1
produto2 -> categoria1
produto3 -> categoria2
```

Gostaria que o resultado da query fosse mais ou menos assim:

```
ID |   Nome   | Quantidade_produtos
 1 |categoria1|         2
 2 |categoria2|         1
 3 |categoria3|         0
```

Porém a query não me retorna isso:

```
ID |   Nome   | Quantidade_produtos
 1 |categoria1|         2
 2 |categoria2|         1
```

Está ignorando as categorias que não possuem nenhum produto cadastrado:

```
 3 |categoria3|         0
```

Alguma dica pra conseguir listar todas as categorias com a quantidade de produtos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invés de INNER JOIN com a tabela de produtos faça LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.nome,t1.imagem,COUNT(t2.*) AS Quantidade_produtos
FROM categorias_produtos AS t1
LEFT JOIN produtos AS t2 ON t2.ref=t1.id GROUP BY t1.id
```

Pois o LEFT JOIN ele irá pegar tudo desde que contenha o registro na tabela a esquerda, já no inner ele teria de possuir o id nas duas tabelas para ele poder retornar um resultado para aquela linha e quando não possui o registro na tabela de produtos, ele irá ignorar essa linha caso seja usado inner join, por isso o uso de left join é o correto

Comment: Por que left join? poderia complementar a resposta explicando a diferença?

Comment: LEFT JOIN ele irá pegar tudo desde que contenha o registro na tabela a esquerda, já no inner ele teria de possuir o id nas duas tabelas para ele poder retornar um resultado para aquela linha e quando não possui o registro na tabela de produtos, ele irá ignorar essa linha caso seja usado inner join, por isso o uso de left join é o correto.

Comment: hmmm, fiz isso e me retornou quantidade 1 para todos que tinha 0, os outros ficaram certo

Comment: altere o COUNT(*) para COUNT(t2.ref), pois ae ele só vai contar os registros da tabela de produtos e não das duas tabelas. Qualquer dúvida é só dizer.

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado :D

Comment: Marque como resolvida a questão. Obg.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio só uma dica, edite sua pergunta, adicionando a explicação do `LEFT JOIN` nela. Fica mais fácil para ser lida como resposta do que como comentário por quem não está habituado com o modelo do SO (no caso visitantes desavisados)